# mariadb returns null values for join with group_concat after certain row count

Tags: mariadb, group-concat

- Locally MariaDB 10.5
- Server upgrade from MariaDB 10.3 -> 10.5 (server is master slave replication)

I have huge query with many joins and almost each has **group_concat**.
To simplify the problem - it is this:

```
SELECT editions_data.editionNames,
       editions_data.editionIds,
       p.id 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `e`.name SEPARATOR ",") AS `editionNames`,
                    GROUP_CONCAT( `e`.id SEPARATOR ",") AS `editionIds`,
                    pe.product_id as productId
                    FROM products_editions pe
                    LEFT JOIN editions e ON e.id = pe.edition_id
                    GROUP BY pe.product_id
              ) as editions_data ON p.id = editions_data.productId
WHERE p.id IN (...)
```

Locally it works fine. On server with 10.3 it worked fine. After upgrade on 10.5 it started to do this:

When I send 70 ids it returns correct data for each row. When I send 71 or more ids it returns first row with correct data and other rows have editions_data as null.

I tried to swap 70th and 71st id so there is not any problem with data. But for 70 ids it works and 71 ids it doesnt.

70 ids

```
editionNames | editionsIds | p.id
rock oldies  |     1       |  1
rock oldies  |     1       |  2
  indies     |     2       |  3
```

71+ ids

```
editionNames | editionsIds | p.id
rock oldies  |     1       |  1
    null     |    null     |  2
    null     |    null     |  3
```

**group_concat_max_length = 1048576** on both servers.

Edit: add db-fiddle as requested in comment https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8H8oiFAnRKAAB4esUCbRCH/0

Comment: Note there's a [maximum number of bytes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#group_concat_max_len) allowed for output from `GROUP_CONCAT` (1K bytes for MariaDB <10.2.4, and 1M bytes since 10.2.4). That said, unless the names are _excessively_ (1000+ chars) long, I don't see you hitting that limit with only 70 entries, unless that variable is tuned to be lower. I'm uncertain if the query will make all `GROUP_CONCAT` null in this case, or only the one that was called.

Comment: Is there something special about that 71st entry (e.g. a `NULL` name or id)? If so, `GROUP_CONCAT` will return `NULL` when aggregating a list of values with a `NULL` inside of it. This would particularly be the case if that `LEFT JOIN` did not find a matching entry in the `editions` table. Try running the subquery itself directly for a problematic product ID, without the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Rogue I increased group_concat_max_len to double and still didnt return 71 ids.
That record is normal. As I said if I swap 71st id and 70th id and then I get 70 ids only it returns correctly.

Comment: You should create a reproducible example of this on a dbfiddle.

Comment: @erik258 I cannot create an example when there is no mariadb on dbfiddle. Also I cannot even reproduce the problem locally.
I can try to simulate sth.

Comment: @erik258 there is dbfiddle with that example. But it works. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8H8oiFAnRKAAB4esUCbRCH/0

Comment: As an example of the problem I noted: remove the `, (3, 2)` from the end of your `INSERT INTO products_editions...` line. If `ON e.id = pe.edition_id` doesn't find a match, the joined columns will be filled with `NULL`.

Comment: @Rogue That simulates missing values.  Just note - the problem is not caused that those data are missing. They are correct in database just maria dont return them.

Comment: @Rogue Most aggregation functions, including `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignore null values, they don't cause the result to become null.

Comment: @Barmar The values are not null.

Comment: I understand that, I was just explaining to them why it doesn't matter.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in 10.5. If you just execute the subquery by itself, do you see the rows with `productId = 2` and `productId = 3`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I do. If I run only the subquery it works even for thousands of rows.

Comment: @Barmar I got caught by the varargs `expr` accepted by `GROUP_CONCAT`, d'oh. If one of those expressions evals to `NULL` for the whole grouping (e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(1, NULL)`), then the whole concat is `NULL`. Otherwise it's as you said. A bug would be a little surprising imo, would definitely like a reproducible case.

Comment: Then it really sounds like a bug. As a workaround, try creating a temporary table with the results of the subquery, and join with that.

Comment: @Rogue I was talking about `GROUP_CONCAT(columnname)` where some of the columnname values are null.

Comment: Problem is I cannot create workaround because I would have to rewrite dozens of those scripts...

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting that doesn't require some recoding?

Comment: Locally I have 10.5.17-MariaDB and server has 10.5.21-MariaDB-1:10.5.21+maria~deb10-log. So it should be newer. I will try to use the same locally and test it with clone of production database.

Comment: @Barmar if there is a bug I would just downgrade to that working version. I understand I would have to recode but it is not possible to do it in reasonable time when I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem on this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VLopLjSl).

Comment: @wchiquito It looks like there is a limit for records. Cannot add milions of records to simulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug. Not because of group_concats but because of group by in left joins. We found that the problem is caused in **optimizer_switch** by **split_materialized=on**.

When I set **split_materialized=off** it starts to work properly. But there is huge duration difference then so there is need to optimize the request (instead of 700ms, it takes 96 s).

So the solution is:

```
SET [SESSION|GLOBAL] optimizer_switch = 'split_materialized=off';
```

Better to use only session where the problem is because of the huge performance drop.